# Custom fields not saving in newest Wordpress 3.0.1

Tags: custom-post-types

I had this working a couple of weeks ago and the only thing I can think is that WordPress has updated and broken the functionality?

I followed the tutorial here to add custom fields: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/wordpress/rock-solid-wordpress-3-0-themes-using-custom-post-types/

It was working fine (I entered about 50 custom posts all with custom fields) but when I go to edit it today any changes I make to the custom fields are not being saved, although other changes work fine.

Does anyone know if this is a known bug?

**Edit:** Here is the code, added in functions.php to a brand new install (theme: twentyten)

```
add_action('init', 'testimonials_register');
add_action("admin_init", "admin_init");
add_action('save_post', 'save_testimonial');




function testimonials_register() {
    $args = array(
        'label' => __('Testimonials'),
        'singular_label' => __('Testimonial'),
        'public' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'menu_position' => 5,
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'rewrite' => true,
        'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail','custom-fields', 'revisions', 'excerpt', 'page-attributes')
    );

    register_post_type( 'testimonials' , $args );
}




register_taxonomy( 'testimonial_project_type', array("testimonials") , array( 'hierarchical' => true, 'label' => 'Project Type', 'query_var' => true, 'rewrite' => true ) );



function admin_init(){
    add_meta_box("testimonialInfo-meta", "Testimonial Options", "meta_options_testimonial", "testimonials", "advanced", "high");

}



function meta_options_testimonial(){
    global $post;
    $custom = get_post_custom($post->ID);
    $name = $custom["name"][0];
    $position = $custom["position"][0];
    $project_url = $custom["project_url"][0];
    $website = $custom["website"][0];
    ?>
  <label for="name" style="width:90px;display:inline-block">Name:</label> <input size="50" name="name" id="name" value="<?php echo $name; ?>" /><br>
  <label for="position" style="width:90px;display:inline-block">Position:</label> <input size="50" name="position" id="position" value="<?php echo $position; ?>" /><br>
  <label for="website" style="width:90px;display:inline-block">Website Name:</label> <input size="50" name="website" id="website" value="<?php echo $website; ?>" /><br>
  <label for="project_url" style="width:90px;display:inline-block">Project slug:</label> <input size="50" name="project_url" id="project_url" value="<?php echo $project_url; ?>" /> <small>E.g. 'parker-harris'</small><br>
    <?php
}

    function save_testimonial(){
$custom_meta_fields = array( 'project_url','name','position','website');
foreach( $custom_meta_fields as $custom_meta_field ):
    if(isset($_POST[$custom_meta_field]) && $_POST[$custom_meta_field] != ""):
        update_post_meta($post->ID, $custom_meta_field, $_POST[$custom_meta_field]);
    endif;
endforeach;


    }








    add_filter("manage_edit-testimonials_columns", "testimonials_edit_columns");  
    add_action("manage_posts_custom_column",  "testimonials_custom_columns");  

    function testimonials_edit_columns($columns){  
    $columns = array(  
        "cb" => "<input type=\"checkbox\" />",  
        "title" => "Testimonial Title",  
        "name" => "Name",  
        "description" => "Excerpt",  
        "project_url" => "Project Slug"
    );  

    return $columns;  
   }  

    function testimonials_custom_columns($column){  
    global $post;  
    switch ($column)  
    {  
        case "name":  
            $custom = get_post_custom();  
            echo $custom["name"][0].", ".$custom["position"][0]."<br> ".$custom["website"][0];
            break;  
        case "description":  
            the_excerpt(); 
            break;  
        case "project_url":  
            $custom = get_post_custom();  
            echo "<a target='_blank' href='/portfolio/".$custom["project_url"][0]."'>".$custom["project_url"][0]."</a>";
            break;  
    }  
    }  









    // This shows testimonials in blog and feed.

    add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_get_posts' );

    function my_get_posts( $query ) {

if ( is_home() && false == $query->query_vars['suppress_filters']  || is_feed() )
    $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'testimonials') );

return $query;
    }
```

Comment: By the way, this is NOT the other saving problem which has cropped up from those tutorials (Autosaving wiping out the data) as I fixed that and this does not save it at all, nit just on a timer. But it was working fully just a few weeks ago!

Comment: My custom post types work just fine. Instead of linking us to the tutorial please provide a link to your code in something like pastie.org or http://gist.github.com/ then we can dig through your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I put your code in a plugin and had to change two things to get it working:

- In `save_testimonial()`, you use `$post` but don't declare it as a global. So `$post->ID` will be empty, and `update_post_meta()` does not know what to save. Add `global $post;` at the beginning of the function.
- `register_taxonomy()` is not in your `init` handler, and is probably called too early (if it is a plugin, maybe you were lucky when you did this in `functions.php`). Move it to the `testimonals_register()` function.

Did you have `WP_DEBUG` set to `TRUE` when you were debugging it? Then you should have gotten the warnings that lead me to this solution.

Comment: Thanks, that worked! It must have been removed from the code somehow... :)